# Firefox is not displaying Navbar images properly other browsers don’t have this issue

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4, navbar

Page is not showing photos in a  proper way in Firefox browser unlike other browsers which are working well , i'm using bootstrap 4

[Chrome View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDwC0.jpg)

[Firefox View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUAaS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding class define the minimum  width and height for images:

```
.img-nav{
  min-width: 108px;
  min-height: 64px;   
}
```

it works well on all browsers.